# django_mptt model with post_save signal

Tags: django, django-mptt

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']



@receiver(post_save)
def translate_name(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if sender not in [Category]:
        return
    if created:
        # some operations with 'name_ru' 'name_en' fields (since django-modeltranslation)
        instance.save(update_fields=['name'])
```

raises **"A node may not be made a child of any of its descendants"**

```
node        <Category: Obj3>
right       3L
target      <Category: Obj2>
level       1L
self        <mptt.managers.TreeManager object at 0x108a76d10>
width       2L
new_tree_id 2L
tree_id     2L
position    u'last-child'
left        2L
```

When I exclude Category model from this post_save handler - everything works

```
Django==1.8.2
django-mptt==0.7.4
```

Any ideas or workaround ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  def move_to(self, target, position='first-child'):
>     """
>     Convenience method for calling ``TreeManager.move_node`` with this
>     model instance.
>     NOTE: This is a low-level method; it does NOT respect
>     ``MPTTMeta.order_insertion_by``.
>     In most cases you should just move the node yourself by setting node.parent.
>     """
> ```

```
if instance.parent:
    instance.move_to(instance.parent)
instance.save(update_fields=updated_field_list)
```